# NSAutoreleasePool in NSOperation main?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, multithreading

The documentation for `+[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:]` says:

> For non garbage-collected applications, the method `aSelector` is responsible
>   for setting up an autorelease pool for the newly detached thread and freeing
>   that pool before it exits.

My question is, do I need to create my own `NSAutoreleasePool` in my override of the `-[NSOperation main]` method, or is the creation of the `NSAutoreleasePool` handled by `NSOperation`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you do. You're defining a self-contained piece of work which the NSOperationQueue will execute on "some" thread, so you're responsible for managing memory in that work piece.

Answer (score 14):

Good question, even Apple's own documents and example code aren't very clear on this. I believe I've found the answer though:

> Because operations are Objective-C
>   objects, you should always create an
>   autorelease pool early in the
>   implementation of your task code. An
>   autorelease pool provides protection
>   against the leaking of Objective-C
>   objects that are autoreleased during
>   your task’s execution. Although there
>   might already be a pool in place by
>   the time your custom code is executed,
>   you should never rely on that behavior
>   and should always provide your own.

Basically, even though there may be a pool in place as David mentioned, you should still create your own.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to create your own NSAutoreleasePool in your main, the system does it for you. To see this, use the Xcode menu command Run > Show> Breakpoints to open the Breakpoints window and type in:
-[NSAutoreleasePool init]

Now run your program, and you'll see an autorelease pool getting created inside NSOperation.

See also, Apple's examples, for example, http://developer.apple.com/Cocoa/managingconcurrency.html which don't create their own autorelease pool.

Comment: I think that you have to if they aren't mainThread NSOperations, based on the other comments here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to create an `NSAutoreleasePool` in your `[NSOperation main]` method, unless you are creating a "concurrent" (slightly unfortunate nomenclature) `NSOperation` subclass and your overridden `[NSOperation start]` method creates the `NSAutoreleasePool` before calling `[NSOperation main].

The `NSOperation` class documentation has a good description of all of this:
http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to.

```
- (void) main
{
  NSAutoreleasePool *thePool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  //your code here
  //more code
  [thePool release];
}
```

if you don't create an autorelease pool, any convinience class-initializer (like [NSString stringWithFormat:]) will leak as these initializers return autoreleased objects.

Comment: As per Apple Documentation, you shouldn't call release for an autoreleasePool, you should call drain.