# NSAutoReleasePool Leaking

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, asihttprequest, nsautoreleasepool

Can anyone tell me why is NSAutoreleasePool leaking in this code. I am using instruments to check leaks & this code is somehow leaking. Can anyone guide me to the right direction. I have the exact same code elsewhere & its running fine.

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:self.url];
 [request setDelegate:self];

 NSOperationQueue *queue = self.downloadQueue;
 [queue addOperation:request];
 [request release];
```

Comment: Does the leak remain if you add `[queue release]` after `[request release]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should go away if you create an NSAutoreleasePool around that code. This usually happens if this code is not being run on the main thread.

```
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
// Your code goes here
[pool drain];
```

Also, be aware that if you are looping inside an NSAutoreleasePool new/drain block, you will appear to leak until you hit the drain. The upshot of this is if you are allocating too much memory inside the loop your app can still run out of memory. In that case you may need to create and drain a second NSAutoreleasePool every time through the loop (or possibly every nth time through the loop to avoid some of the overhead).

Comment: +1 for Mark's comment.  I often see code on a thread entry that creates an autorelease pool and doesn't drain it until the thread exits.  For a long-lived thread or even a short one that allocates a lot of memory (for e.g. images) you need to drain and recreate the pool frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this code on a secondary thread?  If so did you setup an autorelease pool on entry?

Comment: No everything is on main thread I am using NSOperationQueue for multi-threading which I believe takes care of NSAutorelease pool itself.. If I were using NSThread directly on some other thread then I had to create an autorelease pool for that particular thread.. right..? correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: you can try to wrap an NSAutoreleasePool over this function and see if it fix the problem. A AutoreleasePool-leak generally occurs when you try to perform a method in background, which have no AutoreleasePool

Comment: Yes, you must create an autorelease pool in your operation main.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184409/nsautoreleasepool-in-nsoperation-main